# Solving the sliding puzzle-like problem with arbitrary number of holes

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I've tried searching for a while, but haven't come across a solution, so figured I would ask my own.

Consider an MxM 2D grid of holes, and a set of N balls which are randomly placed in the grid. You are given some final configuration of the N balls in the grid, and your goal is to move the balls in the grid to achieve this final configuration in the shortest time possible.

The only move you are allowed to make is to move any contiguous subsection of the grid (on either a row or column) by one space. That sounds a bit confusing; basically you can select any set of points in a straight line in the grid, and shift all the balls in that subsection by one spot to the left or right if it is a row, or one spot up or down if it is a hole. If that is confusing, it's fine to consider the alternate problem where the only move you can make is to move a single ball to any adjacent spot. The caveat is that two balls can never overlap.

Ultimately this problem basically boils down to a version of the classic sliding tile puzzle, with two key differences: 1) there can be an arbitrary number of holes, and 2) we don't a priori know the numbering of the tiles - we don't care which balls end up in the final holes, we just want to final holes to be filled after it is all said and done.

I'm looking for suggestions about how to go about adapting classic sliding puzzle solutions to these two constraints. The arbitrary number of holes is likely pretty easy to implement efficiently, but the fact that we don't know which balls are destined to go in which holes at the start is throwing me for a loop. Any advice (or implementations of similar problems) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well:

- all the balls are equal and cannot be distinguished - they can occupy any position on the grid, the starting state is a random configuration of balls and holes on the grid.
- there are `nxn =  balls + holes = number of cells in the grid`
- your target is to reach a given configuration.

It seems a rather trivial problem, so maybe I missed some constraints. If this is indeed the problem, solving it can be approached like this:

- Consider that you move the holes, not the balls.
- conduct a search between each hole and each hole position in the target configuration.
- Minimize the number of steps to walk the holes to their closest target. (maybe with a BFS if it is needed) - That is to say that you can use this measure as a heuristic to order the moves in a flavor of A* maybe. I think for a 50x50 grid, the search will be very fast, because your heuristic is extremely precise and nearly costless to calculate.

Solving the problem where you can move a hole along multiple positions on a line, or a file is not much more complicated; you can solve it by adding to the possible moves/next steps in your queue.

Comment: That is the gist of it. I guess I was hoping there would be a more deterministic solution than doing an exhaustive search. Ultimately the grid may be large (50x50), with roughly half the holes filled, and the time to find the correct set of moves for a given start/end configurations matters, so doing a BFS search may be grossly too slow. 

Also, if I understand correctly, are you saying it is always optimal to move the a hole to the nearest hole target? I think I'm misinterpreting, because that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: No I did not say that, but you can use this as a heuristic to order the moves in a flavor of A* maybe. I think for a 50x50 grid, the search will be very fast, because your heuristic is extremely precise and nearly costless to calculate.